# Given $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$, find an Explicit definition for $T$, given Transformation matrix and bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be a linear transformation.
>
> Let $B=((1,0,1),(1,1,3),(4,2,7)), \ C=((1,0,1,1),(0,1,1,-1),(0,0,-1,1),(0,0,0,-1))$
>
> $[T]_{C}^{B} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> -1 & 1 & 5\\
> 1 & 0 & -1\\
> 3 & 1 & 2\\
> 2 & -1 & -3
> \end{array}\right)$
>
> Find an explicit definition for $T(x,y,z)$.

***My attempt:***

As $T$ is defined from  $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ then I'm confused about finding $T$.

I know that $[T]_{C}^{B} \cdot [v]_B = [v]_{C}$, but does $[v]_B$ is equal: $(1,1,4)$, which is the first entry of every vector in $B$?

Or if I want to find $T$ using the standard base, do I have to use the standard base of $\mathbb{R}^4$? Or the standard base of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: $v\in\mathbb R^3$ and $Tv\in\mathbb R^4$, so how can you have $[T]_C^B[v]_B=[v]_C$ when $Tv$ can’t possibly be equal to $v$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$(1,0,0)=-(1,0,1)-2(1,1,3)+(4,2,7),\tag1$$you know that$$T(1,0,0)=-T(1,0,1)-2T(1,1,3)+T(4,2,7).$$You also know that:

- $T(1,0,1)=-(1,0,1,1)+(0,1,1,-1)+3(0,0,-1-1)+2(0,0,0,-1)$;
- $T(1,1,3)=(1,0,1,1)+(0,0,-1-1)-(0,0,0,-1)$;
- $T(4,2,7)=5(1,0,1,1)-(0,1,1,-1)+2(0,0,-1-1)+3(0,0,0,-1)$.

So, you know $T(1,0,0)$. By the same approach, you know $T(0,1,0)$ and $T(0,0,1)$. Finally,$$T(x,y,z)=xT(1,0,0)+yT(0,1,0)+zT(0,0,1).$$

**Note:** The coefficients of $(1)$ are easy to obtain as follows: you consider the matrix$$\beta=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 & 7\end{bmatrix},$$whose columns are the vectors of $B$. Then$$\beta^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -5 & 2 \\ -2 & -3 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$and the first, the second, and the third columns of this matrix are $T(1,0,0)$, $T(0,1,0)$, and $T(0,0,1)$ respectively.